# Varnish and IIS

Tags: varnish

I have configured Varnish on Ubuntu 16.04. I have the backeend servers configured and vcl_recv sections. Varnish is configured on Port 80 and the IIS web-servers are also operating on port 80. How do I get the Varnish server to start caching the IIS web-servers. The IIS web-servers are also running Drupal 7 and 8. I have read documentation about using Apache and port 8080 but that isn't my situation. I am not sure how to integrate the caching with the Windows IIS web-servers. My boss has asked ask me to get this working. I know there is a caching ability on IIS but they want to use Varnish. So any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

They can't share port (if on the same host). Otherwise it's perfectly fine to have Varnish running on "host1" on port 80 and IIS on "host2" on port 80.

**If on the same host:**

Either you have to change IIS to work on port 8080 or you have to change Varnish to work on port 8080 and then redirect your incoming traffic to that port.

Comment: My setup isn't using Apache. We are using IIS 8 Webservers and Ubuntu 16.04 with Varnish 4.0. How do I redirect the traffic to hit Varnish first. Right now website are point to Varnish but that isn't working. When someone hits the url it should go to the Varnish server first right.

Comment: IIS or Apache doesn't matter. What matters is if they are on the same machine or not. Same machine = can't share ports. Different machines = different ports.

Comment: The IIS Webservers are on different machine. Varnish is running on Ubuntu 16.04. I have configured the basic default.vcl vcl_recv file but traffic isn't going to Varnish the DNS Admin changed the DNS to point to Varnish but when someone types in the URL getting page not found

Comment: backend drupal {
    .host = "drupal.miat.co";
    .port = "80";
    .connect_timeout = 6000s;
    .first_byte_timeout = 6000s;
    .between_bytes_timeout = 6000s;
}

backend ncwrite {
    .host = "ncwrite.miat.co";
    .port = "80";
    .connect_timeout = 6000s;
    .first_byte_timeout = 6000s;
    .between_bytes_timeout = 6000s;
}

sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.http.host == "drupal.miat.co"){
        set req.backend_hint = drupal;
    } elsif (req.http.host == "ncwrite.miat.co"){
       set req.backend_hint = ncwrite;
       return (hash);
    }
}

Comment: backend drupal {
    .host = "drupal.miat.co";
    .port = "80";
    .connect_timeout = 6000s;
    .first_byte_timeout = 6000s;
    .between_bytes_timeout = 6000s;
}

backend ncwrite {
    .host = "ncwrite.miat.co";
    .port = "80";
    .connect_timeout = 6000s;
    .first_byte_timeout = 6000s;
    .between_bytes_timeout = 6000s;
}

sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.http.host == "drupal.miat.co"){
        set req.backend_hint = drupal;
    } elsif (req.http.host == "ncwrite.miat.co"){
       set req.backend_hint = ncwrite;
       return (hash);
    }
}

Comment: Whats your VARNISH_LISTEN_PORT? Located in your varnish setup file (/etc/sysconfig/varnish or another location depending on installation).

Comment: varnishd -j unix,user=vcache -F -a :80 -T localhost:6082 -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -S /etc/varnish/secret -s malloc,1024m

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand your varnish and iis are not on the same servers (one linux and one windows).

It should be pretty straightforward to set up. Declare your iis servers in the vcl backend section (ip and port 80) and follow the documentation, just keep in mind that your varnish server is not the same as your backend server (iis in your case, apache in the docs).

As for the cache it will depend on your needs. You need to tell varnish what yo cache and how long to cache it. you can do it in different ways (returning a cache control header in your iis web response, hardcode the cache time in varnish...).

Comment: Okay thanks. How can I test the cache does my varnish server need to point to the webservers so when you hit the url it goes to the varnish server first

Comment: When I type in the url right now it isn't available because it is pointing to my varnish server which should get the request first before the web-servers. In the default.vlc the IIS web-servers are configured to use port 80 and varnish is on port 6081. So what configuration is missing to allow the varnish server to get the request first to cache the information.

Comment: port 6081 is for varnish admin I think Varnish is listening to port 80. Could you share your default.vcl and the argument with which you start varnishd?

Comment: varnishd -j unix,user=vcache -F -a :80 -T localhost:6082 -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -S /etc/varnish/secret -s malloc,1024m

Comment: backend drupal {
    .host = "drupal.miat.co";
    .port = "80";
    .connect_timeout = 6000s;
    .first_byte_timeout = 6000s;
    .between_bytes_timeout = 6000s;
}

backend ncwrite {
    .host = "ncwrite.miat.co";
    .port = "80";
    .connect_timeout = 6000s;
    .first_byte_timeout = 6000s;
    .between_bytes_timeout = 6000s;
}

sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.http.host == "drupal.miat.co"){
        set req.backend_hint = drupal;
    } elsif (req.http.host == "ncwrite.miat.co"){
       set req.backend_hint = ncwrite;
       return (hash);
    }
}

Comment: did you change your dns in order  to hit your varnish?